Does anyone know what the 2D Hilbert transform is of $\exp(-(x+y)^2)$?
I'm having no luck finding the 2D Hilbert Transform (standard principle value definition) $f(x,y)=\exp(-(x+y)^2)$. Naively I might expect this to be zero since under change of variables (rotation) to $u=(x+y), v=(x-y)$ the function $f(u,v)=f(u)$ has a 2D Hilbert transform of zero since the 1D Hilbert Transform acting on $v$ is the 1D Hilbert Transform of a constant which is zero. However, I suspect this argument is wrong due to the subtleties of the Principle value definitions under rotation. Does anyone have an answer?

Please give the definition of he 2D Hilbert Transform you have in mind.

$(1/ \pi^2) \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u,v)du dv/((u-x)(v-y))$

I think it is a wrong forum for such questions.

OK. I'll try and post elsewhere (if I can)

That improper  integral diverges for $f(x,y):=\exp(-(x+y)^2)$.

Is this a Mathematica software question or a mathematics question? If the latter, it belongs in [math.se], where it may receive more relevant answers.

Maybe: HilbertTransfrom[f_] :=   InverseFourierTransform[(I*Sign[s])*FourierTransform[f, x, s], s,     u] // Expand; HilbertTransfrom[  HilbertTransfrom[Exp[-(x + y)^2]] /. u -> v /. y -> x] Gives:  -E^-(u + v)^2 ?

Not sure I follow this. I suggested the 2D Hilbert transform of my function was zero, but suspected I was wrong. user64494 says it does not exist (diverges).

By way of background, I thought to use this function as an example of a function which cannot be written as the sum of separable functions $\sum_i f^i_1(x) f^i_2(y)$ for a stringent test of a numerical implementation of the 2D Hilbert transform I'm writing. Obviously I can't if it's zero or does not exist!

I should have said "cannot be written as a finite sum of separable functions".
